# Struggling to connect two phylogenetic trees together in R

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape

I've become very stuck on what I assumed would be a very simple thing and would appreciate any help!

I have two trees that I want to connect together at their roots, whilst preserving both root edges, but everything I try (using `bind.tree`) seems to fail.

First method I tried:

```
bind.tree(treeA, treeB)
```

seems to remove root edges.

2nd method I tried involved creating an "ancestor" tree consisting of these root edges I was trying to conserve and binding both trees to that:

```
Progress_Tree<- bind.tree(anc_tree, TreeA, where = 1)
Error in x$edge[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Or if I unroot TreeA, I can attach it, but when I then attach TreeB, it adds all of the tips of both trees, but only contains a list of a very small number of edges.

I'm just so confused.

Comment: I am not speaking to the code, but the principle, when I say that there are ways to make the trees contradictory.  The trivial case is a binary logistic regression tree, where each split only has 2 branches or leaves, but the labels on the trees are reversed.  They are fundamentally incompatible.  You might be using some sort of ordinal components, things like north, or character strings, instead of characters, but in its guts the problem doesn't just go away.  After you resolve that then there is the software component of the problem.  Could you please make "toy data" so I can help with this?

Comment: I made two much smaller subtrees and converted them to a Newick format to send you and found a solution in the process. When I converted the full trees to Newick strings and then read them back in, bind.tree worked fine, so it must have been related to the formatting somehow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could put the answer as an answer to your question.